# Bootstrap CSS - website Header & Footer are overlapping and the main content is invisible

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

This is the site - http://jnnce.ac.in/jnncenew/JNNCE%20Website/

It works properly on PCs But in mobile devices the layouts are scrambled and placed randomly.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The site has basic problems. It uses fixed width boxes, and also fixed height boxes, which should not be used in a Bootstrap site. https://www.codeschool.com/courses/blasting-off-with-bootstrap

Comment: How shall I proceed now?
Is there anyway to alter the current design with minimal changes?

Comment: First of all you need to know what Bootstrap is, and how it work. When you do, you can alter the current design without too many changes. For instance: remove `height: 160px;` from `.color-bar-2` and put the header as a responsive image in that column. That would fix the header. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Bootstrap, you could use the bult in classes to ensure a mobile friendly site. In my opinion it is best to start with the mobile site (mobile first). So the html code should look more like this (in my opinion):

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
      <h5>About Us</h5>
      <h2>JNNCE</h2>
      <address></address>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
      <h5>Usefull links</h5>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
      <h5>University Links</h5>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
      <h5>Facilities</h5>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you use the bootstrap class col to maintain the mobile structure. The col-12 is for all devices under 540px wide and the col-md-3 is for all devices that are wider. This is one of the reasons bootstrap is widely used, the [grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/). Hope this helps!
Cheers, Steven